# lftp ubuntu cannot local directory

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

```
open ftp://dfg:fdggdfg@iis502.ixwebhosting.com
mirror -v --only-newer --loop /var/ixweb/ /sdf/
```

I have the following in a file and I call it like this

```
sudo lftp -f /root/ftpyncix
```

the error is the following

```
---> CWD /var/ixweb
<--- 550 /var/ixweb: The system cannot find the path specified.
mirror: Access failed: 550 /var/ixweb: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I have tried changing directory's to almost anything in var in root in var/www
I am thinking that the program does not have permision to run on that folder so I 777 nd it with files and still have no luck
I followed the instuctions from here 
http://www.dangibbs.co.uk/journal/ftp-sync-usin-linux
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

lftp is trying to mirror *from* `/var/ixweb` on the FTP server, which doesn't exist. I'm assuming that you want to mirror `/sdf` on the FTP server to `/var/ixweb` on your local machine, in which case you have the directories in the wrong order.

From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/lftp):

> ```
>   mirror [OPTS] [source [target]]
> ```
>
> Mirror specified source directory to local target directory. If target directory ends with a slash, the source base name is appended
>          to target directory name. Source and/or target can be URLs pointing to directories.

So you want:

```
mirror -v --only-newer --loop /sdf/ /var/ixweb/
```